# Bubble sort and input

Tags: java

I have to enter 3 jumpers who will jump 2 times.

Here is an illustration via my console for the first jump. (it's step is ok)

[image]

Then, for the second jump. I have to sort the first jump from the smallest to the biggest.

So, I have to retrieve the jumper Emilie and not Olivia.

I don't understand how to do this ?

[image]

I think my problem is my sortBublle() method ?

```
import java.util.*;
 
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
 
 
    String[] arrayJumper = new String[3];
    int[] arrayJump = new int[3];
 
    encoding_jump_1(arrayJumper, arrayJump);
    sortBublle(arrayJump);
    encoding_jump_2(arrayJumper, arrayJump);
 
 
  }
 
  public static void encoding_jump_1(String[] arrayJumper, int[] arrayJump){
 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 
      int iJumper = 0;
      int iJump = 0;
 
      System.out.println("Jump 1 : ");
 
      for(int i=0; i<arrayJumper.length; i++){
 
        System.out.print("Enter jumper " + (i+1) + " : ");
        String jumper = input.next();
        arrayJumper[iJumper++] = jumper;
 
        System.out.print("Enter for the jumper " + arrayJumper[i] + " the first jump please : ");
        int jump = input.nextInt();
 
        while(jump <= 9 || jump >=111){
          System.out.print("Error ! The jump should to be between 10 and 100 please : ");
          jump = input.nextInt();
 
        }
 
        arrayJump[iJump++] = jump; 
 
      }
 
  }
 
  public static void sortBublle(int[] arrayJump){
 
    int size = arrayJump.length;
    int tempo = 0;
 
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      for(int j=1; j < (size - i) ; j++){
 
          if(arrayJump[j-1] > arrayJump[j]){
            tempo = arrayJump[j-1];
            arrayJump[j-1] = arrayJump[j];
            arrayJump[j] = tempo;
          }
      }
    }
  }
 
  public static void encoding_jump_2(String[] arrayJumper, int[] arrayJump){
 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 
      int iJump = 0;
 
      System.out.println("Jump 2 : ");
 
      for(int i=0; i<arrayJumper.length; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter for the jumper " + arrayJumper[i] + " the second jump please : ");
        int jump = input.nextInt();
 
        while(jump <= 9 || jump >=111){
          System.out.print("Error ! The jump should to be between 10 and 100 please : ");
          jump = input.nextInt();
 
        }
 
        arrayJump[iJump++] = jump; 
 
      }
  }
 
 
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This question has been asked more than 3 times. I am sharing one of the links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616044/bubble-sort-input. So mark it duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only sorting `arrayJump` --> You need to sort both `arrayJumper` and arrayJump`

```
...
if(arrayJump[j-1] > arrayJump[j]){
        tempo = arrayJump[j-1];
        arrayJump[j-1] = arrayJump[j];
        arrayJump[j] = tempo;
        
        tempName = arrayJumper[j-1];
        arrayJumper[j-1] = arrayJumper[j];
        arrayJumper[j] = tempName;
}
```